# Como validar input de tipo date (fecha) - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, laravel-blade, blade

Estoy realizando una aplicacion de un sistema medico donde estoy colocando como uno de mis campos la fecha de nacimiento y estoy usando la palabra 'datepicker'de laravel.Se me esta presentado lo siguiente

[[image: en la imagen se nota un error que no me permite guardar el nuevo paciente ---> validacion 1]

a continuacion muestro mi codigo

Codigo del database

```
return new class extends Migration
```

{
/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function up()
{
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->integer('sanidad')->nullable();
$table->integer('numcolegio')->nullable();
$table->date('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable();
$table->boolean('genero')->nullable();
$table->boolean('estatus')->nullable();
});
}

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('votes');
        $table->dropColumn('sanidad');
        $table->dropColumn('numcolegio');
        $table->dropColumnte('fecha_nacimiento');
        $table->dropColumn('genero');
        $table->dropColumn('estatus');
        
    });
```

codigo del controlador

```
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'id' => 'required|digits:10',
        'address' =>'nullable|min:6',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'fecha_nacimiento'=>'required|date_format:Y-m-d'

        
    ];

    $this->validate($request , $rules);

    User::create(
        $request->only('name','fecha_nacimiento','email', 'id', 'address','phone','genero')
        +[
            'role' =>'paciente',
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password' ))
        ]);
```

Por ultimo el codigo de mi vista

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-calendar-grid-58"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Seleccionar Fecha" type="text" value="2020/06/20" data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd">
               </div>
                @if ($errors->has('fecha_nacimiento'))
                <div class="text-danger"> 
                  {{ $errors->first('fecha_nacimiento') }}
                </div>
                @endif
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crea una validación en el backend y devuelves una respuesta, mira este ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el codigo se debe insertar como texto , no como imagen.L ee [answer]